# Counting regex matches

Tags: java, android, regex, count

I need to count the matches that regex found to declare an array. I tried it with `.groupCount()` but that doesn't seem to be the right thing^^
My code:

```
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("<char>(.*?)</char>");
response = response.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+",  "");
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(response);

String[] chars = new String[m2.groupCount()];
```

It should find 2, but says 1. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you show the string in 'response' ?

Comment: its a very long xml structure, it goes like `<chars><char>...</char><char>...</char></chars>`

Comment: Why should it show 2? You've only got one capture group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupCount()` counts the capturing groups in the `Pattern`, not number of matches.

The easiest way, I would think, would be to use a resizable `List` ([`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for instance) to store your matches, and then convert it to an array if you need to (`ArrayList.toArray()`)